# INSERT INTO another entity using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I want to perform something semantic equally to this query with JPA:

```sql
INSERT INTO second_table(second_id, second_name, audit_cre_at, audit_cre_from)
SELECT first_id, first_name, audit_cre_at, audit_cre_from
FROM FIRST_TABLE f
WHERE f.FIRST_VALID = 1;

DELETE FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE FIRST_VALID = 1;
```

On those tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FIRST_TABLE(
  FIRST_ID          RAW(16)                                   NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FIRST_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(2000),
  FIRST_VALID       NUMBER(1)                                 NOT NULL,
  AUDIT_CRE_AT      TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  AUDIT_CRE_FROM    VARCHAR2(32) DEFAULT 'system'             NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT SECOND_VALID CHECK (SECOND_VALID IN (0,1))
);

CREATE TABLE SECOND_TABLE(
  SECOND_ID          RAW(16)                                 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT SECOND_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  SECOND_NAME        VARCHAR2(2000),
  AUDIT_CRE_AT       TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
  AUDIT_CRE_FROM     VARCHAR2(32) DEFAULT 'system'           NOT NULL,
);
```

This is my `FirstTable` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIRST_TABLE")
public class FirstTable{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Convert("UuidConverter")
    @Column(name = "FIRST_ID")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "FIRST_VALID")
    private int valid;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "AUDIT_CRE_AT")
    private Date createdTime;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "AUDIT_CRE_FROM")
    private String creator;
}
```

And this is my `SecondTable` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECOND_TABLE")
public class SecondTable{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Convert("UuidConverter")
    @Column(name = "SECOND_ID")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "SECOND_NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "AUDIT_CRE_AT")
    private Date createdTime;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "AUDIT_CRE_FROM")
    private String creator;
}
```

I want to execute this in my `FirstTable` Entity. So I guess I have to set up a `SecondaryTable` to access it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIRST_TABLE")
@SecondaryTable(name = "SECOND_TABLE")
@NamedQuery(...)
public class FirstTable
```

I do not want to execute the query I mentioned above, but I would rather perform something similar with JPA (The result shall be the same like the query). How can I do this?

Comment: I think you can't use named queries for insert.Also i think it would be more convenient to use in these cases JPQL or native queries.

Comment: Simply execute the code with multiple calls to JPA: `EntityManager.persist()`, `EntityManager.delete()` and a named queries. Do that in a transaction.

Comment: you can execute any SQL statement in JPA, but WHY you would want to issue INSERT statements when that is what JPA is designed to provide for you ...

Comment: My question was a bit misleading. I corrected it to clarify my question.

Comment: JPA doesn't have any support to do that, other than reading all the entities from the first table, then create corresponding entities for the second table. That will obviously be a lot slower than the SQL query. What's wrong with executing a SQL query?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with executing the query and I guess that's was I'm gonna do. I just thought it would be better to use JPA if it could help me in this case.

Comment: @JBNizet Btw, if you want you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA doesn't have any support to do that, other than reading all the entities from the first table, then create corresponding entities for the second table.

But that will be a lot slower than the SQL query.